# Need to use "new" when adding to a List?

Tags: java, list

I'm new to Java and been trying to figure out if I need to pass a new instance of a class when adding the entry to a list, as such:

```
CCustEntry entry = new CCustEntry();
List<CCustEntry> CustList = new ArrayList<CCustEntry>();
do
{
    // set all entry fields
    entry.id = [...];
    [fill other fields of entry from DB]

    // add entry (constructor copies entry)
    CustList.add( new CCustEntry( entry ) );

} while( C.moveToNext() == true );
```

OR... can I remove new and simply pass entry to the add() method like this:

> ```
>    CustList.add( entry );
> ```

I've been reading about Lists but I'm more confused than I was before. Coming from Delphi and C++, I'm fine with the syntax, but some of the "grammar" of Java still has me scratching my head.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't need to make a new entry if you already have one. Also, java convention is to use lowercase first character for instance names.

Comment: CustList.add(entry) is the right one. Since you declared that CustList will only accept the type CCustEntry which is defined by this line List<CCustEntry>.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if the entry will be modified or not. It sounds like you have a bean that makes a shallow copy of the entry, so if the fields of `entry` will be modified, then you should add a copy. Otherwise, it would be just wasting memory to construct a new one.

Here, it seems like you are using the same entry throughout the loop, so you will want to make a copy. Otherwise, the whole list will contain the same object - i.e., each item is the same object.

Another comment: in Java, it's usual to name fields and values starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you all for the extra info about the lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

It depends: if you don't create a new instance each time, then you will be adding the *same* instance to the list multiple times. This means that if you modify an element at one index of the list, then all of the other elements will also get modified in the same way (since they are all the same instance). If you want distinct but equal instances, then you must create a `new` one each time.